# Modal base оn a[href^="#id"]

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы лишний раз не писать вызовы модалки, по типу:

```
$('#button-1').on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-1').addClass('j-modal--open');
});

 $('#button-2').on('click', function() {
    $('#modal-2').addClass('j-modal--open');
 });
```

и так далее, а написать что-то вроде этого:

```
var modal__id = $('a[href^="#j-form"]').val();

$('a[href^="#j-form"]').on('click', function() {
    $(modal__id).addClass('j-modal--open');
});
```

Где содержимое href вносится в переменную и при клике по ссылке, находится id с таким же названием и к нему добавляется класс j-modal--open

То есть при клике:

```
<a href="#j-form__какой-то-id">Нажать тут</a>
```

Открывалось окно:

```
<div id="j-form__какой-то-id">Контент модалки</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При клике на ссылку берем значение атрибута `href`, далее по нему ищем элемент с таким `id` и добавляем класс:

```
$('a[href^="#j-form"]').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $(id).addClass('j-modal--open');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<a href="#j-form__какой-то-id" class="js-modal-open">Нажать тут</a>
<a href="#j-form__какой-то-другой-id" class="js-modal-open">Нажать тут</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.js-modal-open').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this.hash).addClass('j-modal--open');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @jsp Перепутал href и hash